# tensorflow Tf.cond giving unexpected output

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.6

I seem to be having a misunderstanding on how `tf.cond` works. In the tensorflow [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond), it gives the following example:

```
z = tf.multiply(a, b)
result = tf.cond(x < y, lambda: tf.add(x, z), lambda: tf.square(y))
```

The result of the example, if `x<y` is `True` is `tf.add(x,z)` else `tf.square(y)`

Following this example, I am trying to build a small example with tf.cond and the result doesnt go along the lines mentioned in the documentation.

in my example, `deterministic_action = 4`, `random_action = 11`, `chose_random=False`. The `stochastic_action` should be `4`, instead it is `1`.
Where did the value 1 come from?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

with tf.Graph().as_default():
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        stochastic_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, (), name="stochastic")
        eps = tf.get_variable("eps", (), initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0))
        with tf.variable_scope('test_cond') as sc:
            deterministic_action = tf.random_uniform([], minval=0, maxval=15, dtype=tf.int64, seed=0) # 4
            random_action = tf.random_uniform([], minval=0, maxval=15, dtype=tf.int64, seed=1) # 11
            chose_random = tf.random_uniform([], minval=0, maxval=1, dtype=tf.float32) < eps # False because eps = 0
            stochastic_action = tf.cond(chose_random, lambda: random_action, lambda: deterministic_action) # S_action should be 4 but it is 1
            #output_action = tf.cond(stochastic_ph, lambda: stochastic_action, lambda: deterministic_action)


    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(init, feed_dict={stochastic_ph: True})
    print ("s_ph = ", stochastic_ph)
    d_action = sess.run(deterministic_action)
    print ("det_action= ", d_action)
    r_action = sess.run(random_action)
    print ("rand_action= ", r_action)
    e = sess.run(eps)
    c_action = sess.run(chose_random)
    print ("chose_rand= ", c_action)
    s_action = sess.run(stochastic_action)
    print ("s_action= ", s_action)
    #output = sess.run(output_action)
```

here is the output:

```
python random_vec.py
2018-10-31 09:46:15.028376: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
s_ph =  Tensor("stochastic:0", shape=(), dtype=bool, device=/device:CPU:0)
det_action=  4
rand_action=  11
chose_rand=  False
s_action=  1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are evaluating again in a new sess.run. 
Since you are generating a random number for deterministic_action, the result turns out to be the next random number after 4, which is 1.
Here is the result of your code, when I extract the value of deterministic_action as well in the last step.

Modification:

```
print ("s_ph = ", stochastic_ph)
d_action = sess.run(deterministic_action)
print ("det_action= ", d_action)
r_action = sess.run(random_action)
print ("rand_action= ", r_action)
e = sess.run(eps)
c_action = sess.run(chose_random)
print ("chose_rand= ", c_action)
s_action, d_action = sess.run([stochastic_action, deterministic_action])
print ("s_action= ", s_action)
print ("det_action= ", d_action)
```

Result:

```
s_ph =  Tensor("stochastic:0", shape=(), dtype=bool, device=/device:CPU:0)
det_action=  4
rand_action=  11
chose_rand=  False
s_action=  1
det_action=  1
```

Now all you need to do is run everything in one sess.run

```
d_action, r_action, e,  c_action, s_action = sess.run([deterministic_action, random_action, eps, chose_random, stochastic_action])
print ("det_action= ", d_action)
print ("rand_action= ", r_action)
print ("chose_rand= ", c_action)
print ("s_action= ", s_action)
```

Result:

```
s_ph =  Tensor("stochastic:0", shape=(), dtype=bool, device=/device:CPU:0)
det_action=  4
rand_action=  11
chose_rand=  False
s_action=  4
```

Update:

I was not clear on why the random_uniform generates different values when seed is set. This is because the code is running with the same session object that it initialized the variables with.
Modifying the code with a new session object, this is what happens:

```
print ("s_ph = ", stochastic_ph)
d_action = sess.run(deterministic_action)
print ("det_action= ", d_action)
sess.close()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init, feed_dict={stochastic_ph: True})
s_action = sess.run(stochastic_action)
print ("s_action= ", s_action)
```

Result:

```
s_ph =  Tensor("stochastic:0", shape=(), dtype=bool, device=/device:CPU:0)
det_action=  4
s_action=  4
```

Comment: The seed is fixed. So, irrespective of the session you run in, the random value should always be the same.

Comment: @tandem the sequence of numbers you get would be the same, but not the value every time. If you notice my first result, where I'm just reading out the value of deterministic_action along with stochastic_action that you are getting in your last step. Your deterministic_action is 1, which means your result is also 1. When I put all the evaluations together in a single session run, your deterministic_action is 4, and hence your result is also 4.

Comment: Seed should always give the same random number. as long as it is set. That explanation doesnt still make sense

Comment: @tandem tensorflow computation graphs depend on your initialization. In the above example, you are still using the session object that is initialized at the beginning. This means tensorflow is keeping a track of the state of its variables in the session object, and thus does not reinitialize the random_uniform. Close the session object with sess.close() and then open a new session object and run your stochastic_action variable, it will produce the result 4 as expected.